# SQL Query to present NULL rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table:

```
Table: pn
id, vender, article, sells, date
01, Peter, bread, 10, 02-01-2019
02, Tom, bread, 3, 10-01-2019
03, Paul, water, 3, 05-01-2019
04, Peter, oil, 5, 16-01-2019
05, Paul, bread, 1, 22-01-2019
06, Tom, oil, 2, 30-01-2019
07, Peter, bread, 1, 27-01-2019
08, Tom, oil, 1, 17-01-2019
```

I wish to have a query that will return the sells of every vender, for specific articles, for a specific period of time. Ex: Bread and oil, between 01-01-2019 and 31-01-2019.
The query result should be:

```
Vendor, Article, Sells
Paul, bread, 1
Paul, oil, 0
Peter, bread, 11
Peter, oil, 5
Tom, bread, 3
Tom, oil, 3
```

My problem is since some Vendors have no sells for specific articles, the rows for that Vendor/Article are not printed, like so:

```
Vendor, Article, Sells
Paul, bread, 1
Peter, bread, 11
Peter, oil, 5
Tom, bread, 3
Tom, oil, 3
```

Notice the missing "Paul, oil, 0"

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT pn.vendor, pn.article, SUM (pn.sells)
FROM pn
WHERE pn.date BETWEEN  01.01.2019 AND 31.01.2019
   AND (pn.article = 'bread' OR pn.article = 'oil')   
GROUP BY pn.vendor, pn.article
ORDER BY pn.vendor ASC, pn.article ASC
```

I have tried many different approaches with ISNULL and COALESC with no luck.
Any help is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: On a sidenote: Do you have a vendor table and an article table and foreign keys to them? You should. If not your table can easily contain typos ('Poul', 'braed', ...).

Comment: What is `pn.familia`? This (and the invalid dates of course) makes your query invalid. It also suggests that your data model is bad (probably violating normalization forms). What DBMS are you using? Please always tag SQL questions with your DBMS. If you can run this query, then I guess it's MySQL, which is notorious for silently "repairing" such queries by applying `ANY_VALUE` internally on the column in question.

Comment: the pn.familia is in fact pn.article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values.

```
SELECT v.vendor, a.article, COALESCE(SUM(pn.sells), 0)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT vendor FROM pn) v CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT article FROM pn) a LEFT JOIN
     pn
     ON pn.vendor = v.vendor AND
        pn.article = a.article AND
        pn.date >= '2019-01-01' AND
        pn.date < '2019-02-01' 
WHERE a.article IN ('bread', 'oil')   
GROUP BY v.vendor, a.article
ORDER BY v.vendor ASC, a.article ASC;
```

Notes:

- Use standard date formats for your dates (YYYY-MM-DD is both standard in SQL and ISO 8601 standard).
- Use table aliases qualify all column references.
- I have no idea what `familia` is in the `ORDER BY`.
- In most database you could just list the articles you want as a derived table for `a`.

Comment: Works like a charm, simple and elegant. what if I would like o present a diferent value then 0 wen there are no sells?

Comment: @VicenteChazard . . .You use `coalesce()` and change the second value.  If you want a string, be sure you cast the `sum()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `WHERE` clause to get Paul too. Then use a `case` expression to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT pn.vendor, pn.article,
        SUM (case when pn.date BETWEEN  01.01.2019 AND 31.01.2019
                       and AND (pn.article = 'bread' OR pn.article = 'oil')  then pn.sells
                  else 0 end)
FROM pn
GROUP BY pn.vendor, pn.article
ORDER BY pn.vendor ASC, pn.familia ASC
```